# HTML Form Validation - Check for Specific Characters

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the Html5 pattern to validate my inputs on forms. I need to make sure an input has the following rules:

1. A maximum and minimum of 8 characters
2. The first 3 must be the specific letters wrx (lowercase)
3. The last 5 must be numbers.

Eg. wrx12345

Can I even do this with pattern or do I need to use JavaScript?

Comment: Please do more research and try to fix it, if it's still not working, please add your code to the question even if it's not working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the regex pattern you are looking for is `/^wrx[0-9]{5}$/`. A visual representation of this here:

[image: regex visual]

And implemented in html:

```html
<input name="example" pattern="^wrx[0-9]{5}$">
```

Comment: Perfect and great illustration to make everything sink in. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to have helped. The visual came from debuggex.com it's a great tool and highly recommend.

Comment: Didn't know about [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/). Thanks for sharing it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in Javascript with this regex:
"/[wrz][\d]{5}/g".

To test the minimum = maximum length = 8, you can just test it in javascript.
If the length egual 8, use the regex
Else, show error

I think this could work

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Javascript to do this.
The pattern attribute uses [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) so you can use something like this: ^wrx[0-9]{5}$

The ^ and $ indicates the start and end of the string. Then 'wrx' has to be matched exactly and [0-9]{5} looks for 5 number bewteen 0-9.
You can use something like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) to test your patterns.

Comment: Thank you very much. Makes sense.